# Can I enter Ireland and work, using my German-issued refugee document?

Tags: germany, ireland, refugees

I have a refugee document issued by Germany. Am I able to travel to Ireland and seek employment with just this, or do I need some sort of permission for that?

Answer (score 1):

Your refugee travel document, also called Convention 1951  document, issued by Germany does allow you to enter Ireland, but only for a visit, not to work.

[The Republic of Ireland Naturalisation and Immigration Service](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/Convention%20travel%20documents) (updated on 20 Jan 2017):

> A holder of a Convention travel document may not be subject to an Irish visa requirement for short stays of up to 90 days in Ireland.
>
> You must have immigration permission to stay in Ireland for longer than 90 days if you are a non-EU/EEA and non-Swiss citizen. [To request permission](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/immigration-permission-finder), submit an application via a scheme or programme.